# Ranking something in an app

Tags: android

I am writing an app that contains different kind of jokes and I want to use something like database to rank jokes. The user should be able to change ranks and when the app is closed the ranks will save and when it opens every joke has its last rank. I have read different example of database but I don't know how implement that code. Would you please help me?

Comment: What do you expect to find here, that you couldn't find in a [beginners tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)?

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html There is some excellent content regarding android development. You'd be interested in the UI elements and data storage with a sqlite database, I guess.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it appears to be a request for someone else to write the code or explain how to write the code, and does not identify a specific problem or question about programming. Please include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differed from the expected results, and any error messages you received. Please read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store it locally you should have a look at the `SharedPreferences` class. You can then store a joke id with the rating on the device. There are enough examples on this technique.

If you want to store it on you server you should make some PHP scripts and a MySQL database. This would be more interesting and more difficult. In the database you store the questions + id + rating. Maybe you can update that database so users gets new jokes when opening your app again. With the PHP script you let your app communicate with the MySQL database. Like updating and retrieving information.